# Java checking if object is an instance of type

Tags: java

Good day Devs. I am trying to compare a passed in object to the expected type. My syntax feels off and i believe the solution is right around the corner. Is what I am doing logical or possible? The error thrown is "pExpectedType cannot be resolved to a type"

```
     /**
     * Tests whether the specified object is an instance of the expected type and throws an exception if the expected type is not in the inheritance hierarchy of the object.
     * @param pValue    The object the test expects to be of the specified type.
     * @param pExpectedType The expected type of value.
     * @param pMessage  The message to include in the exception when value is not an instance of expectedType. The message is shown in test results.
     * @param pParameters   An array of parameters to use when formatting message.
     * @throws AssertFailedException    Thrown if value is null or expectedType is not in the inheritance hierarchy of value.
     */
    public static void IsInstanceOfType (Object pValue, Class<?> pExpectedType, String pMessage, Object[] pParameters) throws AssertFailedException
    {
        if(pValue == null || pValue instanceof pExpectedType == false)
            throw new AssertFailedException(String.format(pMessage, pParameters));
    }
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: pExpectedType cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Should Object pValue be the generic object instead of Object type ?

Comment: you mean the expectedtype? no this is intentional

Comment: if i wanted it the way you are suggesting, the function would be called IsInstanceOfSpecificType

Comment: You don’t need that method at all.  Java already provides it:  `assert value instanceof SomeType : "Expected value to be a " + SomeType.class;`  And you should avoid prefixing every parameter with `p`.  It provides no benefit and makes the code harder to read.

Comment: there is more to the method, this is just showing what is needed to the users on here.

Comment: i disagree, its a coding standard that brings more information, it doesnt make it harder to read, you just dont like it.

Comment: for example, whats the difference when assigning a parameter to a local variable... variable = variable or variable = pVariable;  see what i mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
if (!pExpectedType.isInstance(pValue))
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach is fine and should work by checking whether pExpectedType is an instance of pValue.

`if(!(pValue instanceof pExpectedType))`

All the same, another approach could be to use reflection. For eg :

```
public static void isInstanceOfTypeWithReflection(Object pValue, Class<?> pExpectedType, String pMessage, Object[] pParameters) throws AssertFailedException {
    Class cls = pValue.getClass();

    if(!pExpectedType.isAssignableFrom(cls)){
        throw new AssertFailedException(String.format(pMessage, pParameters));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are three ways to test if an object matches an expected class:

1. Using [`isInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-) is the "dynamic equivalent of the Java language instanceof operator".
2. Comparing the output of [`getClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--) will match exact classes only.
3. Using [`isAssignableFrom()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom-java.lang.Class-) will check if the class is "the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the class or interface represented by the specified Class parameter".

```
public static void comparisonExamples(Object o, Class<?> expectedClass) {
    if (expectedClass.isInstance(o)) {
        // ...
    }

    if (o.getClass() == expectedClass) {
        // ...
    }

    if (o.getClass().isAssignableFrom(expectedClass)) {
        // ...
    }
}
```